# Missing number, treated as zero on section using package titlesec

Tags: titlesec, layout, section-titles, missing

When using the `titlesec` package to modify the layout of the chapter title, I get the error: ***Missing number, treated as zero.***, in the section title.

I use the following code to perform this action:

```
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

throwing error in the first section within the first chapter.

[image: Error]
[image: Errorr]

The only way I have found to avoid generating an error is to remove this design. But I require to place this.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example (MWE) of your current code which reproduces the mentioned problem.

Comment: For now I would say: where does the second bracket after the label come from? And: it is not wise to name a label sec:1.1, because you will make mistakes when you put a new section before it in future (take a word from the section title instead). Third: maybe the point in the label causes the mistake. Fourth: otherwise indeed provide for an MWE.