# Overlapping text?

Tags: overlap

I have seen that in some of the SE entries, such as [Missing number, treated as zero on section using package titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602344), that the start of a comment overlaps the end of the question.

How could I do this with LaTeX? Consider two paragraphs in the source where in the typeset output the words in the bottom half of the first paragraph are overlaid by the words in the top half of the second paragraph. I'm not sure I would ever want to do this, but if I did, how could I?

How does SE manage to do it? Is it controlled by SE or is it something done by the respondents?

Comment: I can't see what you mean in the link provided. Can you provide a screen shot of what you're referring to?

Comment: You could just issue a negative `\vspace` to let content overlap, I guess...

Comment: as Werner says `\vspace{-5cm}`  between the paragraphs will make the latex paragraphs  overlap, but I see no overlapping in the page that you link to?

Comment: @Werner I don't know how to provide a screen shot. I have a nasty feeling that it is my viewer (Mozilla Firefox) that is causing the SE problem. Anyway, never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative `\vspace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\vspace{-\dimexpr\parskip+3\baselineskip}% Overlap 3 lines of the previous paragraph

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```